# To classify bifurcations by calculating partial derivatives evaluated at the bifurcation point

Tags: nonlinear-system, chaos-theory, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

**Question:**  Given a one dimensional system $\dot{x} = f(x;\; \mu)$ for which a bifurcation of fixed points occurs at  $(x^\star, \mu_c)$, where $x^\star$ is a fixed point and $\mu_c$ is the corresponding bifurcation parameter value, can we classify the bifurcation point using the same criteria as is used to classify the bifurcation points of iterated maps (see below)?

---

**Context:** To classify bifurcations for iterated maps $x_{n + 1} = f(x_n;\; \mu)$ we have the following criteria. In the following the partial derivatives of $f$ are evaluated at $(x^\star, \mu_c)$,

*Saddle node bifurcations:* $f_x = 1$, $f_{xx} \neq 0$, $f_\mu \neq 0$

*Transcritical bifurcations:* $f_x = 1$, $f_{xx} \neq 0$, $f_\mu = 0$, $f_{\mu x}^2 - f_{xx} f_{\mu \mu} \neq 0$

*Pitchfork bifurcations:* $f_x = 1$, $f_{xx} = 0$, $f_\mu = 0$, $f_{\mu x} \neq 0$, $f_{xxx} \neq 0$

*Period doubling bifurcations:* $f_x = -1$, $2f_{\mu x} + f_{\mu} f_{xx} \neq 0$, $f_{xx}^2/2 + f_{xxx}/3 \neq 0$.

---

**Remarks:** Of course, the $f_x = \pm 1$ criteria will have to be replaced with $f_x = 0$.

**Related question:** Do period doubling bifurcations occur in continuous systems of the form  $\dot{x} = f(x;\; \mu)$, or do they only occur in iterated maps?

Comment: Regarding the last question: one-dimensional continuous-time system can't have periodic solutions (except fixed points, if you count that as periodic), so you have to go to higher dimensions to make that question meaningful.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, since one dimensional systems are all conservative by the existence of an anti-derivative.

Comment: As stated, provided that $f_x = \pm 1$ is substituted for $f_x = 0$, the criteria above (with the exception of the period doubling bifurcation criterion), do indeed apply to continuous one dimensional systems [1].

[1]: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/yanghong.huang/teaching/MATH4041/part4.pdf

Comment: I've found a reference in the lecture notes above, but the link will one day die. If someone is able to find a textbook (and chapter number) reference, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.